# Problems installing mountain lion

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, downgrade

I have been fighting to downgrade my MacBook Pro 2012 to mountain lion. I accidentally let it update to catilina. I struggled to create the bootable usb according to all the videos online (ended up using super duper to create one) now when i boot with option I get into the mountain lion installer I can’t see my hard drive I only have the option to install to the the usb which won’t work either

Answer (score 1):

A quick check at [everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/by_year/macs-released-in-2012.html) shows the earliest OS X that can be installed on a 2012 MacBook Pro model is between OS X 10.7 3 and OS X 10.8.2 inclusively. Therefore, you should be able to install Mountain Lion on your Mac. However, [everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-2.9-21-inch-aluminum-late-2013-specs.html) shows the earliest OS X that can installed on my iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013) is
OS X 10.8.4 and I can not boot from any OS X 10.8.5 installer created using instructions given in this answer. My 2011 iMac will boot without any issues.

Catalina uses APFS which will not be recognized by Mountain Lion. After booting from the Mountain Lion installer, you will need to open the Disk Utility and erase the entire internal drive. You should choose "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" as the format. Use "GUID Partition Map" as the scheme.

Since you have stated you have correctly created the USB Mountain Lion installer, I will not post how to do so. However, if you are still unable to install, perhaps you should include in your question the steps you used to create the installer.

---

### Update 1: Test Install of Mountain Lion

I did download the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file for OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion) from [How to download macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683) on a iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013) with macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina) installed. I was able to create a Mountain Lion bootable installer from this downloaded file. I did not need to use any third party tools (such as [SuperDuper](https://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html)) to create the installer. I used the bootable installer to install Mount Lion in a VMware Fusion Player (Version 12.1.0) virtual machine. After installing, I was able to download and install all available updates except for an update to iTunes 12.14.3. I was able to [download this update](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683) on the host and transfer the update to the virtual machine where installation was successful.

---

### Update 2: How to Get the `InstallESD.dmg` File from Apple

This was tested using macOS Catalina (10.15.7).

1. From [How to download macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211683), download the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file for OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion) to your `~/Downloads` folder.
2. Enter the command below to open `InstallMacOSX.dmg`. This will mount the readonly Mac OS Extended (HFS+) volume on `/Volumes/Install Mac OS X`.

   ```
   hdiutil attach ~/Downloads/InstallMacOSX.dmg
   ```
3. Enter the command below to extract folders and files from `InstallMacOSX.dmg` to the `~/Downloads/pkg` folder. Here, I assume the `~/Downloads/pkg` folder does not already exist.

   ```
   pkgutil --expand /Volumes/Install\ Mac\ OS\ X/InstallMacOSX.pkg ~/Downloads/pkg
   ```
4. Enter the command below to eject `/Volumes/Install Mac OS X`.

   ```
    diskutil eject /Volumes/Install\ Mac\ OS\ X/
   ```
5. Use the command below to move the `InstallESD.dmg` file to the `~/Downloads` folder.

   ```
   mv ~/Downloads/pkg/InstallMacOSX.pkg/InstallESD.dmg ~/Downloads/
   ```
6. Use the Finder application to move the `~/Downloads/pkg` folder to the Trash.
7. (Optional). To save space, you can move the downloaded file `~/Downloads/InstallMacOSX.dmg` to the Trash, then empty the Trash.

I should point out that the `InstallMacOSX.dmg` file can be used to create an `Install OS X Mountain Lion` application. This application also contains an `InstallESD.dmg` file in the `Contents/SharedSupport` folder. While these two `InstallESD.dmg` files are different sizes, the contents are identical.

---

### Update 3: Creating a APM USB Flash Drive Installer

I was unable to use the Disk Utility included with Catalina to create a bootable USB flash drive installer. So I used the following steps to transfer an exact image from the `InstallESD.dmg` file to the flash drive.

1. Insert a 8 GB or larger USB flash drive.
2. Enter the command below to open `InstallESD.dmg` file. This will mount the readonly Mac OS Extended (HFS+) volume on `/Volumes/Mac OS X Install ESD`.

   ```
   hdiutil attach ~/Downloads/InstallESD.dmg
   ```
3. Enter the command below to determined the identifiers for the external, physical USB flash drive and the disk image. In my case, the flash drive has been assigned `disk5` and the disk image has been assigned `disk6`. If your assignments are different, then make the appropriate substitutions in the following steps.

   ```
   diskutil list
   ```
4. Unmount all volumes on both the flash drive and disk image by entering the commands given below.

   ```
   diskutil unmountdisk disk5
   diskutil unmountdisk disk6
   ```
5. Enter the command below to transfer a exact copy of the disk image to the flash drive.

   > Note: The transfer occurs faster when the identifiers are proceeded by the letter `r`.

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk6 of=/dev/rdisk5 bs=1m
   ```
6. Enter the command below to eject the mounted disk image.

   ```
   diskutil eject disk6
   ```

Note: The flash drive is using the Apple Partition Map (APM).

### Update 4: Converting from APM to GPT

If your Mac can not boot from a flash drive using the Apple Partition Map (APM), then use the following steps to covert to a GUID Partition Table (GPT).

1. Enter the command below to get the beginning partition offset in sectors (512-Byte-Device-Blocks) of the volume labeled `Mac OS X Install ESD` on the USB flash drive installer. Also, get the disk (partition) size in sectors (512-Byte-Units). If your identifier for the USB flash drive installer differs from `disk5`, then make the appropriate substitution.

   ```
   diskutil info disk5s2 | grep -e Offset -e Size

      Partition Offset:          32768 Bytes (64 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)
      Disk Size:                 4.9 GB (4856860672 Bytes) (exactly 9486056 512-Byte-Units)
      Device Block Size:         512 Bytes
      Allocation Block Size:     4096 Bytes
   ```

   > Note: You can get the same values by using the `sudo pdisk -l /dev/disk5` command. However, you will need to multiply the `base` and `length` values by 4 to convert to the `Partition Offset` and `Disk Size` 512 byte sector values shown above.
2. Enter the commands below to create the GUID Partition Table (GPT). Use the offset and size values determined in the previous step. If your values are different for the identifier, offset and/or size, then make the appropriate substitutions. The `gpt destroy` command may generate an error message which can be ignored.

   > Note: The offset follows the `-b` option and the size follows the `-s` option.

   ```
   diskutil unmountdisk disk5
   sudo gpt destroy disk5
   diskutil unmountdisk disk5
   sudo gpt create disk5
   sudo gpt add -i 1 -b 64 -s 9486056 -t hfs disk5
   ```

   **The rest of the steps are optional.**
3. Turn on journalling.

   ```
   diskutil enableJournal disk5s1
   ```
4. Add free space to the volume.

   ```
   diskutil resizevolume disk5s1 R
   ```
5. Rename the volume.

   ```
   diskutil renamevolume disk5s1 "Install Mountain Lion"
   ```
6. Add an icon which appears in the Mac Startup Manager on some Macs.

   ```
   cp /Volumes/Install\ Mountain\ Lion/Install\ OS\ X\ Mountain\ Lion.app/Contents/Resources/InstallAssistant.icns /Volumes/Install\ Mountain\ Lion/.VolumeIcon.icns
   ```
7. Change the label. The current label which appears in the Mac Startup Manager is `Mac OS X`. The command below changes this label to `Install Mountain Lion`.

   ```
   sudo bless --folder /Volumes/Install\ Mountain\ Lion --label Install\ Mountain\ Lion
   ```

Comment: To create the usb I followed these instructions except when it got to restoring in disk utility as it continuously failed. then used super Duper’s restore function to create the USB with that ESD installer. I can boot the mountain lion installer, but the usb is still labelled untitled

Comment: @KaneSmith: What are *"these instructions"*? Did you intend to include a link in your previous comment?

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/create-bootable-copies-os-x-mountain-lion-installer-2260352